# How can constants WM_IME_COMPOSITION and WM_IME_KEYLAST have the same value

Tags: winapi

The constants `WM_IME_COMPOSITION` and `WM_IME_KEYLAST` both have the same value `0x010F`. Seems like a windows program that receives one of these window messages would not know which message it received. So how would one write code to handle these messages?

I am asking out of curiosity. I do not need to handle either `WM_IME_COMPOSITION` or `WM_IME_KEYLAST`. Was simply looking through some documentation and noticed the strange thing that I do not understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WM_IME_KEYLAST` is not a message identifier. It is a symbolic constant that marks the end of the `WM_IME_*` range of messages<sup>1</sup>. You see this pattern throughout the Windows SDK, e.g. there are `WM_KEYFIRST` and `WM_KEYLAST` symbols that describe the range of values related to key messages.

To answer your question: You do not handle `WM_IME_KEYLAST`, so there is no ambiguity. You can (and should) use it in expressions, where you want to handle a range of messages, for example.

---

<sup>1</sup> *Although in this particular case I'm not entirely sure, as there is no corresponding `WM_IME_KEYFIRST` symbol. `WM_IME_KEYLAST` might just be an obsolete name, where the then unused message value was reused for the new `WM_IME_COMPOSITION` message. Once shipped, you cannot go back and remove the symbol, so it's still there, but doesn't serve any purpose anymore.*